# Setting file name for saving .JPG

Tags: android

I am stuck.  I am converting a LinearLayout to a Bitmap, saving it, and then E-mailing it.  The issue I have is I want to set the file name so it overwrites the previous file name. The main purpose is to email the LinearLayout as an image.  From what I read you have to save it to the SD card first.  I am fine with that but I only want to have one saved image at all times.  I am getting a file name with what seems like a random 13 digit file name like (1329676773253.jpg) Here is the code.

```
void image() {

    llImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    test2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(llImage.getDrawingCache());
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, "001");
    values.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "ast.jpg");
    values.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

    Uri uri2 = getContentResolver().insert(
            Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    try {
        OutputStream outStream = getContentResolver()
                .openOutputStream(uri2);
        test2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        Log.d("done", "done");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(
            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri2);
    emailIntent.setType("image/png");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            Html.fromHtml("" + finalEmail));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));

}
```

Comment: If you want a fixed name, why not just use a fixed name? e.g. (/mnt/sdcard/myimage.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write to file with `FileOutputStream`:

```
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("filename.jpg");
```

Comment: That in theory would let it overwrite, but the main purpose is to attach the image to an E-Mail.  How do I call this as a Uri then?

Comment: `Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("filename"));`

Comment: I think you solved my problem...but where is it saving the file?  Before I was able to find  it on the SD card and now I can't.

Comment: Internal memory assigned to app: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal This memory is scarce but you should be ok just for one file. External memory (sd-card) can be risky, as it might not be available (not mounted or not-writable).

Comment: Looks like I am back to square one.  Other apps can't get this data therefor GMail app can't send the Image.  When you go to send it it shows as an attachment, but when sent there is no attachment.  Any other ideas?  I can update code if you think that this should still work.

Comment: Hmm. Try using `FileOutputStream outStream = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE)`

Comment: Can't seem to get that to work either.  Do you know where my file name was coming from my original code?  There has to be an easy way for me to define it.